# xslt 1.0 - translate stirng backslash to double backslash

Tags: json, xslt-1.0

My xml:

```
<workorder>
    <specifications>
        <hpath>94 \ 72</hpath>
        <classdesc></classdesc>
    </specifications>
</workorder>
```

my xslt:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="workorder">        
         <xsl:apply-templates select="specifications" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="specifications">
    <xsl:text>{
    "Hierarchy Path"="</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(//workorder/specifications/hpath,'\','\\')" />
       <xsl:text>"
     }</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expecting output is:

```
   {
    "Hierarchy Path"="94 \\ 72"
     }
```

Current output is :

```
   {
    "Hierarchy Path"="94 \ 72"
     }
```

Problem is: When I send json format as "Current output", not a valid json format.
If I send as "Expected output", it is a valid json format.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 you need a recursive approach.
You may try something like this named template.

```
<xsl:template name="jsonescape">
 <xsl:param name="str" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($str, '\')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($str, '\'), '\\' )"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="jsonescape">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str, '\')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And call it with your strings(for example).

```
<xsl:call-template name="jsonescape">
    <xsl:with-param name="str" select="//workorder/specifications/hpath"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: @hr_117 @hr-117 Is there a way to make it valid for any char passed as param? So that any char could be escaped... i tried adding a `param name="char"` in the template and `<xsl:with-param name="char" select="/"/>` to see if the slash would be escaped, but i obtain compiling errors